# Error handling post request in Django and getting "Too long to shutdown and was killed"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, daphne

I am running daphne server in production and getting following error

```
Application instance <Task pending coro=<AsgiHandler.__call__() running at /home/coldbrewtech/frnd/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/http.py:213> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/futures.py:403, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f0b49b6a6a8>()]>> for connection <WebRequest at 0x7f0b48daa438 method=POST uri=/api/getMessages clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

It is happening in following POST request:

```
class GetRoomMessages(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        room_no = request.data.get('room_no', None)
        message_id = request.data.get('message_id', None)
        order = request.data.get('order', None)
        message_instance = None

        if(order == 'old'):
            try:
                message_instance = Message.objects.filter(room_no=room_no, id__lt = message_id).order_by('-id')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return status_500()
        elif(order == 'new'):
            try:
                message_instance = Message.objects.filter(room_no=room_no, id__gt = message_id).order_by('id')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return status_500()

        if(message_instance is not None):
            serializer = MessageSerializer(message_instance, many=True)
            return status_200("success", serializer.data)
        else:
            return status_400("Invalid Request")
```

I am not sure why this is happening, but it happens when there are a lot of messages to serialize. I don't think it is taking time to serialize but rather I think the size of response might be too big. Is that the case in general? If not, can you please tell me what is the reason for same?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I was not running the appropriate version of python required by Django Channels. So, I updated the python version and it worked fine after that.

Comment: @hardik24  I have the same issue and tried python 3.7 and 3.9 to no avail, what version of python did you use please?